# SQL SERVER order by random in series

Tags: sql, database, random, sql-order-by, sql-server-2000

I want to display records in random order, the simplest answer is `order by NEWID()`, that's fine.

I have `EmployeesID` from `1` to `100`. The output needs to be displayed in random series, i.e.

```
30.31.32.33...40..20.21.22..30..80.81.82..90.1.2.3..10..and so on..
```

If there are 100 records, it should be divided into 10 parts and every part displays randomly.

CODE I tried is:

```
select empId,empName from employees
where empID between 1 and 100
order by NEWID()
```

INPUT
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99  100

OUTPUT
50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99  100 30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90

Comment: please post the Input and Output..question is quite unclear

Comment: SQL server 2000? `NEWID()` was presented in 2008 R2 as I remember

Comment: NEWID() is working fine in SQL SERVER 2000

Comment: From MSDN `NEWID (Transact-SQL) SQL Server (starting with 2008)`. Check `SELECT @@VERSION`. What this query would return? Anyway, did you check my answer?

Comment: Microsoft Sql Server 2000 - 8.0.194 Aug 6 2000

Answer (score 0):

I will use `NORTHWND.[dbo].[Employees]`, it got 9 employees.

```
USE tempdb;
GO
SET NOCOUNT ON;
CREATE TABLE #SAMPLE_DATA
(
    empID int,
    ni uniqueidentifier 
);

INSERT INTO #SAMPLE_DATA(empID, ni ) 
SELECT  [EmployeeID], NEWID()
FROM NORTHWND.[dbo].[Employees]
ORDER BY NEWID()

DECLARE @Values VARCHAR(1000)

SELECT @Values = COALESCE(@Values + ' ', '') + CAST(empID AS varchar(50))
FROM #SAMPLE_DATA
ORDER BY ni 

SELECT @Values;

DROP TABLE #SAMPLE_DATA;
```

Output:

```
2 6 4 1 3 9 7 8 5
```

Next run:

```
8 5 3 1 6 4 7 9 2
```

etc

Comment: but your query shows output as i mentioned in the question.
select empid from employees
order by newid()
plz read the question again and try regarding required OUTPUT

Comment: Only `empId`'s space separated string?

Comment: every emp have assigned id from 1 to 100.. I want to show these 100 records in 10 packets (or array of 10 x 10 = 100) in a random sequence

Comment: So... 10 rows and in each 10 `empID`s or 1 row with `/r/n` after each 10 `empID`s? In your question there is only 1 string with randomize `empID`s.

Comment: yeah 10 x 10, empId is Int data type

Comment: I'm writing from my phone, so can not post code. But I have solution. Put randomized empid's in a temp table, create another table with ten columns, col1, col2... etc, then do while loop, paste top 10 from temp table in col2, delete pasted from temp table, next run update col2 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```sql
    --drop table #data
    select 1 as row
    into #data
    union all select 2
    union all select 3
    union all select 4
    union all select 5
    union all select 6
    union all select 7
    union all select 8
    union all select 9
    union all select 10
    union all select 11
    union all select 12
    union all select 13
    union all select 14
    union all select 15
    union all select 16
    union all select 17
    union all select 18
    union all select 19
    union all select 20
    union all select 21
    union all select 22
    union all select 23
    union all select 24
    union all select 25
    union all select 26
    union all select 27
    union all select 28
    union all select 29
    union all select 30
    union all select 31
    union all select 32
    union all select 33
    union all select 34
    union all select 35
    union all select 36
    union all select 37
    union all select 38
    union all select 39
    union all select 40
    union all select 41
    union all select 42
    union all select 43
    union all select 44
    union all select 45
    union all select 46
    union all select 47
    union all select 48
    union all select 49
    union all select 50
    union all select 51
    union all select 52
    union all select 53
    union all select 54
    union all select 55
    union all select 56
    union all select 57
    union all select 58
    union all select 59
    union all select 60
    union all select 61
    union all select 62
    union all select 63
    union all select 64
    union all select 65
    union all select 66
    union all select 67
    union all select 68
    union all select 69
    union all select 70
    union all select 71
    union all select 72
    union all select 73
    union all select 74
    union all select 75
    union all select 76
    union all select 77
    union all select 78
    union all select 79
    union all select 80
    union all select 81
    union all select 82
    union all select 83
    union all select 84
    union all select 85
    union all select 86
    union all select 87
    union all select 88
    union all select 89
    union all select 90
    union all select 91
    union all select 92
    union all select 93
    union all select 94
    union all select 95
    union all select 96
    union all select 97
    union all select 98
    union all select 99
    union all select 100
```

```sql
    select  d.*, x.newid
    from    (
        select (row-1) / 10 AS row, MAX(CAST(NEWID() AS NVARCHAR(100))) AS newid
        FROM #data
        GROUP BY (row-1) / 10
        ) x
    INNER JOIN #data d
        ON  (d.row-1) / 10 = x.row
    order by x.newid, d.row
```

The base idea is to have a derived table where you group rows by 10, and then generate a MAX(NEWID()), this will distribute the random value per group, and then you just sort by it